# How should I capitalize Ruby?

Tags: ruby, coding-style, capitalization

RUBY? Ruby? ruby? What's good style?

I know the answer—I just wanted to make sure the question was out there and questioners were aware that there is a correct form.

Also, should I capitalize "gem" as "GEM"?

```
class TestLanguageName < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_language_name
    assert_correct_language_name StackOverflow.new.describe_language("RuBy")
  end
end

class StackOverflow
  def describe_language(string)
    # Which of the following?
    methods = [:upcase, :capitalize, :downcase]
    string.send(methods[rand(3)])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Section 1.9 of [ruby-doc.org FAQ](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/FAQ/FAQ.html) says:

> Officially, the language is called
>   "Ruby". On most systems, it is
>   invoked using the command "ruby".
>   It's OK to use ruby instead of Ruby.
>   Please don't use RUBY as the language
>   name. Originally, or historically, it
>   was called "ruby".

Either Ruby or ruby is correct.

Answer (score 8):

The programming language is called **Ruby** (that's how they write it on [the official site](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/)).

As for gems, the full name of the project is [**RubyGems**](http://rubygems.org/), with inner-caps, but the things you produce for it are simply **gems** (unlike a lot of open-source projects, it doesn't stand for anything — it's just a pun on "Ruby").

As a side note, even though the language is "Ruby", the name of the official Ruby interpreter on most systems is **ruby** — the capitalization matters here because many filesystems are case-sensitive, so trying to run "Ruby" will get you a whole bunch of nothing. But to distinguish it from other Ruby interpreters, in conversation this implementation is usually called "MRI" (for "Matz's Ruby Interpreter").