# Reason(s) why method runs when boolean is not set to an instance variable?

Tags: ruby

I'm just starting Ruby and have a beginner question. Why is it that when `pin_number == @pin` (in the `display_balance` and `withdraw` methods), I get an error, but when I edit to set `pin_number == pin`, both methods then work?

In the methods below, I have the `private` class `pin` setting `@pin = 1234`, so I thought that should have worked using `@pin` and not `pin`.

```
class Account
  attr_reader :name, :balance
  def initialize(name, balance=100)
    @name = name
    @balance = balance
  end

  def display_balance(pin_number)
    if pin_number == @pin
      puts "Balance: $#{@balance}"
    else
      pin_error
    end
  end

  def withdraw(pin_number, amount)
    if pin_number == @pin
      @balance -= amount
      puts "Withdrew #{amount}. New balance #{amount}."
    else
      pin_error
    end
  end

  private
  def pin
    @pin = 1234
  end

  def pin_error
    return "Access denied: incorrect PIN."
  end
end

checking_account = Account.new("Rick", 1_000_000)
checking_account.display_balance(1234)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Below the methods, I have the private class pin setting @pin = 1234, so I thought that should have worked using @pin and not pin.

No; `pin` calls that method, which both sets `@pin = 1234` and returns its value.

Referencing `@pin` just references that variable and nothing more; it does not invoke the private `pin` method.

I believe this should answer your other questions.

Comment: The language is "Ruby" because it is the proper name of the language. Invoking it is "ruby". If you're going to refer to it as a command on the command line, then mark it as `code` or a TTY-like format. If you think they are the same then why use "C++" and "C#"?

Comment: @theTinMan http://stackoverflow.com/a/6053314/2700898 I'm not saying this is the case for all languages, but it is so for ruby and perl, for example.

Comment: I'd trust http://stackoverflow.com/a/6053302/128421. You'll notice that the references, including the FAQ being quoted, all refer to "Ruby" and "Perl" when discussing the language.

Comment: These are statements from the FAQ in the context of what to call the language: "It's OK to use ruby instead of Ruby." and 'Originally, or historically, it was called "ruby".'